# Stop Activity Indicator in Status Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm near completing my application, but I'm running into an issue. Obviously, my web view needs an activity indicator for the app to be accepted. I have the following already:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]]; // I removed the website for privacy's sake

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Problem is that it won't stop spinning when I need it to (i.e. even after the page is loaded, it doesn't stop)

Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` in your class file that holds the `UIWebView`, and insert the following two methods:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

In the start method, place your:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

... and in the finish, place:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In the web views delegate you can do:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

to get it to stop